# Show that a function is not integrable over an unknown interval

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, riemann-integration

Let $g:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be defined by

$g(x) =
\begin{cases}
3,   \text{ if x is rational}\\
2,  \text{ if x is irrational}
\end{cases}$

Show that $g(x)$ is not integrable.

--

So far I have said that for any dissection $D=(x_0,...,x_n)$ we have

$\inf f[x_{i-1}, x_i]=2$, and

$\sup f[x_{i-1}, x_i]=3$

as we know that every interval will contain both rationals and irrationals.

From here, if I had a defined interval eg. [0,1] I would simply find the upper and lower sums but I am not sure what to do in the case of our arbitrary interval [a,b] as ultimately I think we need to show

$\sup${$\underline{s}(D):D\in D$} < $\inf${$\overline{s}(D):D\in D$}

Where would I go from here?

Comment: I think you've basically answered your own question here: "as we know that every interval will contain both rationals and irrationals". You can just say that every interval in any partition of $[a, b]$ will contain rationals and irrationals, hence the upper and lower Darboux sums will differ by $1$ times the length of the interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information that you have given regarding $\sup$ and $\inf$ of $f$ over an interval suffices.

Indeed, a function is Riemann integrable, if its upper Riemann sum coincides with its lower Riemann sum.

However, let us take any interval $[a,b]$ over which we are checking Riemann integrability, and any partition $a = t_0 < t_1 < ... < t_n = b$. Then, the lower Riemann sum is $$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (t_{i+1} - t_i)[\inf_{[t_i,t_{i+1}]} f] = 2 \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (t_{i+1} - t_i) = 2(b-a)$$

*Regardless of the partition*.

Similarly, the upper Riemann sum is $3(b-a)$ regardless of the partition. Even if I make the partitions finer and finer,  the lower and upper sums don't come closer to each other because they are fixed non-equal numbers.

Consequently, the function is not R.I. over any $[a,b]$, $b > a$.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: You are welcome! You can upvote if you liked the answer. I have up voted your question, it is very nicely written.

Comment: It won't let me upvote until I have 15 reputation, but I definitely will when I do!

Comment: Great , thanks so much for your reply.